# Salt-Cloud and local development

Tags: amazon-web-services, saltstack, salt-cloud

I want to create basic aws infrastructure(vpc,subnets,route tables/routes,ec2 boxes) using saltstack.

I am using a centos vagrant box as my salt master and minion as well to create vpc, subnets and routes using salt states.

But the problem occurs when I try to spin up ec2 boxes from my vagrant using salt-cloud and then again configuring them using the state files. Minions created in aws aren't able to talk to my master on the vagrant as I am on private network.

Alternatively, I've tried to put my salt-master on an ec2 instance which works fine, except development is a pain as I have to write all salt scripts from inside the ec2 box, which is less than ideal for our dev team.

I would like to make this setup work from the vagrant box as my salt master.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that takes your local changes and puts into your EC2 box(which you can use for testing your in-development changes). While you do this you have to be sure that your script takes care of resolving conflicts while multiple devs are working on it. This can be achieved by applying local changes always on a different location.
If done correctly, it could be as simple as :
Execute_My_Changes_On_Remote.sh